# Strange behaveiour of <button> with <i> formatting

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on claculator and one of the buttons doesnt responds as rest. First click on it doesnt log to the console. After I click a button for root and then go to square it starts to work. I notice that whe i remove  tag then it is working normally

```
<button class="btn instant-operator btn--squere" data-tab="x2">
          <i>x<sup>2</sup></i>
        </button>
        <button class="btn instant-operator btn--root" data-tab="root">
          &#x221A;x
        </button>
```

Some JS code:

```
function instantOperator(iOperator) {
  console.log(iOperator);
}

    const actionBtn = function (e) {

      const clicked = e.target;
      clicked.classList.remove("btn--clicked");
      void clicked.offsetWidth; // trigger reflow
      clicked.classList.add("btn--clicked");
    
      if (clicked.classList.contains("integer")) {
        integer(clicked);
      } else if (clicked.classList.contains("operator")) {
        operator(clicked);
      } else if (clicked.classList.contains("instant-operator"))
        instantOperator(clicked);
    };
    
    btnsBody.addEventListener("click", actionBtn);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) is normally the element the user clicked on. If you click on the text inside a nested node, the `event.target` will be the respective node.

From MDN:

> The read-only target property of the Event interface is a reference to the object onto which the event was dispatched. It is different from Event.currentTarget when the event handler is called during the bubbling or capturing phase of the event.

```js
b1.onclick = (event) => { console.log(event.target.outerHTML) }
b2.onclick = (event) => { console.log(event.target.outerHTML) }
```

```html
<button id="b1"><i>Click on the text</i></button>
<button id="b2">Click here <i>not here</i></button>
```

You can avoid this, by looking at the event path using [event.composedPath()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath):

```js
b1.onclick = (event) => {
  event.composedPath().forEach(node => {
    if (node.nodeName == "BUTTON") {
      console.log(node.outerHTML);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<button id="b1"><i>Click on the text</i></button>
```

By using css `pointer-events: none;` for all child elements of a button:

```js
b1.onclick = (event) => { console.log(event.target.outerHTML) }
```

```css
#b1 > * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="b1"><i>Click on the text</i></button>
```

Or by using the [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) or `this` inside normal functions.

```js
b1.onclick = (event) => { console.log(event.currentTarget.outerHTML) }
b2.onclick = function(event) { console.log(this.outerHTML) }
```

```html
<button id="b1"><i>Click on the text</i></button>
<button id="b2"><i>Click on the text</i></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

use **e.currentTarget**

target returns clicked element

currentTarget returns your event binded element

look below

```js
function instantOperator(iOperator) {
  console.log(iOperator);
}

    const actionBtn = function (e) {

      const clicked = e.currentTarget;  // here use **currentTarget** like this or use **this**
//const clicked = this;
      clicked.classList.remove("btn--clicked");
      void clicked.offsetWidth; // trigger reflow
      clicked.classList.add("btn--clicked");
      if (clicked.classList.contains("integer")) {
        integer(clicked);
      } else if (clicked.classList.contains("operator")) {
        operator(clicked);
      } else if (clicked.classList.contains("instant-operator"))
        instantOperator(clicked);
    };
    var btnsBody = document.getElementById('x2');
    btnsBody.addEventListener("click", actionBtn);
```

```html
<button id = 'x2' class="btn instant-operator btn--squere" data-tab="x2">
          <i>x<sup>2</sup></i>
        </button>
        <button id='rtx' class="btn instant-operator btn--root" data-tab="root">
          &#x221A;x
        </button>
```